# How to upload ssrs rdl files to SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2014, msbi

We have installed SQL Server 2014 on a web server. And we have connected to the SSRS Reporting Services, but we don't see any options (like import report) to upload into the reporting services.

Can anyone plase guide on this one how to get/upload report the reporting services?

Comment: Should see it somewhere like... `http://serverName/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx` and a button for Upload FIle

Comment: Thanks. it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the Report Manager portal (e.g. http://yourserver/Reports)
and once you're there and you have the appropriate permissions, there will be an Upload File button.

You should see something like this: [image]

You can also deploy a reports project to the server rather than uploading each one, directly from SQL Server Data Tools

Comment: Thanks for the above reply. but when currently our sql version is 2005 it has the facility to upload from ssrs reporting services from SQL. So Does the latest version 2014 is providing the interface like above ?  Currently we are accessing the reports from webapplocation by uploading to reporting services of 2005.

Comment: As far as I know, you can upload reports to 2014 just as you could via 2005: either from your development project (what used to be called BIDS in 2005 but is now called SQL Server Data Tools), or in the portal. So nothing has changed.